# Magnolia CMS : Introducing Magnolia tutorial not working with Magnolia CE and EE

Tags: templates, tomcat, bundle, magnolia

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba4cBygYhhg), but in the `Template*` combobox there is no "hello" template after I created the directories and files structures under the magnoliaAuthor.

I tried with CE and EE variant of Magnolia travel demo Tomcat bundle (version 5.4.6), but no success.

I saw entry in catalina.out:

```
2016-05-19 10:26:03,863 INFO  agnolia.config.source.yaml.YamlConfigurationSource: Registered DefinitionMetadataBuilder.DefinitionMetadataImpl(type=TEMPLATE, referenceId=hello-magnolia:pages/hello, name=hello, module=hello-magnolia, location=/hello-magnolia/templates/pages/hello.yaml, relativeLocation=pages/hello) from LayeredResource{path='/hello-magnolia/templates/pages/hello.yaml', layeredResources=[FileSystemResource{origin=filesystem,path=/hello-magnolia/templates/pages/hello.yaml,file}]}
```

But the "hello" does not appear in the `Template*` combo box, when I try to create a new Page. The bundle restart didn't help either.

The example project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipxu6mklk3t4dqt/hello-magnolia.zip?oref=e) if you need to try it out to see what is wrong.

Comment: Can you please post your configuration here FTL and YAML files ? and also directory names are important here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying with 5.4.6 you are most likely running into https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLDEMO-158

Demo is now showcasing also how you can limit template availability to different sites, but that makes little sense in CE where you can have only one site, and even with EE it makes it more difficult to experiment with the product.

Long story short, workaround for until that issue is solved, just log in to AdminCentral, got to WebDev/Site, open site definition for your site and delete `/<your_site_definition>/templates/availability` node. All should be working then.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. It is realy helped: "just log in to AdminCentral, got to WebDev/Site, open site definition for your site and delete /<your_site_definition>/templates/availability node. All should be working then."